# "boxes of strawberries" or "boxes of strawberry"?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

"Give me six boxes of strawberry"

or

"Give me six boxes of strawberries"

As far as I know, the word "strawberry" is a countable noun in English. If so, then the second should be the correct sentence.

However, if the first one is correct, can you, please, provide explanation as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "strawberries" form is more common.  The "strawberry" form could happen if the speaker considers the "strawberry" to represent a substance. For "strawberries" that would be unusual.  (Or it could be a mistake.)